# Java - Reorder Map<String, List<String>>

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, hashmap

I have a Map < String, List< String>> called data and looks like this

```
data = {Salad=[Salad Bar Station, Green Pepper & Tomato Salad, Lo Mein Noodle Salad], 
        Pizza=[Cheese Pizza - Slice, Pepperoni Pizza, Tomato Bruschetta Flatbread Pizza, Herb 
               Seasoned Breadsticks, Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits], 
        Dessert=[Carnival Cookies, Sweet Cinnamon Brownies, Oreo Crumble Pudding Cup, 
                 Cherry Jell-O Parfait], 
        Cold Cereal=[Miscellaneous/Peripherals]}
```

Now I want to reorder this so it looks like this

```
data = Pizza=[Cheese Pizza - Slice, Pepperoni Pizza, Tomato Bruschetta Flatbread Pizza, Herb 
               Seasoned Breadsticks, Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits], 
       Salad=[Salad Bar Station, Green Pepper & Tomato Salad, Lo Mein Noodle Salad],
       Cold Cereal=[Miscellaneous/Peripherals]
       Dessert=[Carnival Cookies, Sweet Cinnamon Brownies, Oreo Crumble Pudding Cup, 
                 Cherry Jell-O Parfait]}
```

Now I have some pseudo-code about how to do this just not quite sure how to do it in code.

So I want to have an array with the order of the keys I want. So it would be like

```
String[] desiredOrder = {"Pizza","Salad","Cold Cereal"};
int destination = 0;
```

And then have something like

```
for (int i=0; i < desiredOrder.length; i++) {
     //then find if the first desiredOrder object is in the data array
         //then check if it is in the right spot
             if (it is in right spot) {
                 //do nothing
             }
             else {
                  //move it to the right spot
             }
 }
```

I would really appreciate it you could help me fill in the rest so that the key and its values are moved to the right spot.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**EDIT**

To make this I am parsing xml from the web and here is what I am doing, notice I changed it to LinkedHashMap just now, so now it gets it in the order of the xml, but I still want to rearrange it to my own order.

```
String currentDay = "";
String currentMeal = "";
String counter = "";

 LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> itemsByCounter = new LinkedHashMap<String , List<String>>();
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xmlData.getName();
            blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("day")) {
                        currentDay = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("meal")) {
                        currentMeal = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter") && currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                        counter = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                    }

                    break;
                case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                    if (currentDay.equalsIgnoreCase(day) && currentMeal.equalsIgnoreCase(meal)) {
                        if (xmlData.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                            items.add(xmlData.getText());

                        }

                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("counter")) {
                        if (items.size() > 0) {
                            itemsByCounter.put(counter, items);
                            items = new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            eventType = xmlData.next();
        }
```

Sorry its quite long, but basically it is just grabbing items adding one as the key and then the ones under that as the values.

Here is how I fill my ListView with my data.

```
MyCustomAdapter mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Object[] array = data.keySet().toArray();
        String string = array[i].toString();
        mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(string);
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < data.get(string).size(); i2++) {
            mAdapter.addItem(data.get(string).get(i2));
        }

    }
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();

    public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        // save separator position
        mSeparatorsSet.add(mData.size() - 1);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mSeparatorsSet.contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cell_view, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    Context context = DiningItemsActivity.this;
                    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_cell_view, parent, false);
                    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSeparator);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colorBar);
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is the point? Maps usually don't have a specific order (e.g. the HashMap is ordered by the key's hash...)

Comment: @MichelMichaelMeyer I am using this data and displaying it in a list view, and I want the more important data at the top, I use the key as the section header and the values and the data in that seciton

Comment: @iqueqiorio have a look at answer, does it help you, use `linkedHashMap `

Comment: Can't you just iterate through desiredOrder, use its Strings as Keys and pass them into the list view successively?

Comment: @MichelMichaelMeyer would you mind posting what you mean, its hard to tell from just that

Comment: Well, how exactly do you fill the list view with the contents of your map?

Comment: @MichelMichaelMeyer see addition to edit

Comment: Instead of using `Object[] array = data.keySet().toArray();` you could simply use your `desiredOrder` array to insert the items. Then no rearranging inside the map is needed, you just insert the items in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

i think using **linkedHashMap** should solve your problem. Either use the `linkedHashMap` in the starting itself or and it will maintain the order or fill it from your another map and `iterate`.

**Pseudo code to fill myMap**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
        String[] desiredOrder = { "Pizza", "Salad", "Cold Cereal", "Dessert" };

        Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> myList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> myList4 = new ArrayList<String>();

        myList1.add("Salad Bar Station, Green Pepper & Tomato Salad");
        myList1.add("Lo Mein Noodle Salad");
        myMap.put("Salad", myList1);

        myList2.add("Cheese Pizza - Slice");
        myList2.add("Pepperoni Pizza");
        myList2.add("Tomato Bruschetta Flatbread Pizza");
        myList2.add("HerbSeasoned Breadsticks");
        myList2.add("Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits");
        myMap.put("Pizza", myList2);

        myList3.add("Carnival Cookies");
        myList3.add("Sweet Cinnamon Brownies");
        myList3.add("Oreo Crumble Pudding Cup");
        myList3.add("Cherry Jell-O Parfait");
        myMap.put("Dessert", myList3);

        myList4.add("Miscellaneous/Peripherals");
        myMap.put("Cold Cereal", myList4);

        System.out.println(myMap);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < desiredOrder.length ; i++) {
            linkedHashMap.put(desiredOrder[i], myMap.get(desiredOrder[i]));
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println(linkedHashMap);
    }
```

**Output**

> {Salad=[Salad Bar Station, Green Pepper & Tomato Salad, Lo Mein Noodle
>   Salad], Dessert=[Carnival Cookies, Sweet Cinnamon Brownies, Oreo
>   Crumble Pudding Cup, Cherry Jell-O Parfait], Cold
>   Cereal=[Miscellaneous/Peripherals], Pizza=[Cheese Pizza - Slice,
>   Pepperoni Pizza, Tomato Bruschetta Flatbread Pizza, HerbSeasoned
>   Breadsticks, Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits]}

---

> {Pizza=[Cheese Pizza - Slice, Pepperoni Pizza, Tomato Bruschetta
>   Flatbread Pizza, HerbSeasoned Breadsticks, Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato
>   Bits], Salad=[Salad Bar Station, Green Pepper & Tomato Salad, Lo Mein
>   Noodle Salad], Cold Cereal=[Miscellaneous/Peripherals],
>   Dessert=[Carnival Cookies, Sweet Cinnamon Brownies, Oreo Crumble
>   Pudding Cup, Cherry Jell-O Parfait]}

Comment: I tried this and some of the values became null and it removed the other keys that were in the original data, if there are other keys I just want them to stay put no be deleted

Comment: right, okay I got the same output but I don't want dessert to be deleted, is there a way around that without having it in the desired order array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66958/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-ankur-singhal).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    List<String> order;
    public TestComparator(String[] desiredOrder) {
        order = Arrays.asList(desiredOrder);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        String[] desiredOrder = {"Pizza","Salad","Cold Cereal"};
        TreeMap<String, List<String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(new TestComparator(desiredOrder));

        //add into Map
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Integer index1 =order.indexOf(o1);
        Integer index2 =order.indexOf(o2);
        return index1.compareTo(index2);
    }
}
```

Comment: does this remove the other keys and values? Or will it keep the at the end of the TreeMap?

Comment: It will reorder after insert a new element based on TestComparator

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar with this class and implementation and am getting compile error `Class 'Test Compare' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method Compare(T,T)`

Comment: Now I have corrected some display issue. Please copy and paste

Comment: Okay so now to call it I have this. `TestComparator testComparator = new TestComparator(desiredOrder);` and then what?

Comment: @iqueqiorio It will reorder your map based on TestComparator implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66957/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-siva-kumar).